# Проблема с foreignKey

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ForeignKey

у меня есть модель:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    CHOICES_status = (
        ('0', 'статус отключен'),
        ('1', 'в поиске'),
        ('2', 'в космосе'),
        ('3', 'женат'),
        ('4', 'член партии'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, choices=CHOICES_status, default='0')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='userprofile/', blank=True)
    nation_show = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
```

она работает. проблема в том, что я хотел бы список статусов хранить не в константе CHOICES_status, а в отдельной табличке

для этого я создаю и заполняю таблицу, которой соответствует следующая модель:

```
class UserStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

но я не понимаю как связать эти две модели(таблицы)

если делаю так:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.ForeignKey()
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='userprofile/', blank=True)
    nation_show = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
```

, то во-первых не работает, а во-вторых непонятно где указание использовать выпадающий список

подскажите пожалуйста примером кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И не должно работать :)

ForeignKey, если говорить просто, должен показывать что вот такое-то поле(в вашем случае status) может принимать значения из такой-то таблицы(в вашем случае UserSatatus), для этого 1м аргументом этот класс принимает таблицу, значения которой может принимать поле.

```
   status = models.ForeignKey(UserStatus)
```

Тогда в админке у вас будет как раз выпадающий список(при условии, что в таблице UserStatus есть записи).

Comment: теперь понятнее. только у меня не через админку происходит выбор статуса. я сделал систему регистрации и каждый зарегистрированный пользователь имеет персональную страницу, на которой может поменять свои анкетные данные. в том числе выбрать статус

Comment: Ок, значит у вас есть класс формы? можно в нем написать подбное

    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserStatus.objects.all(), label=_(u'status'), widget=forms.Select())

Comment: Если форма делается из модели, лучше использовать ModelForm, тогда руками прописывать не нужно ничего.